# Regular expression /2 same letter/ PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

Hey im looking for resolution to my problem at PHP.
How to create regular expression which will check that I get two of the same letter from range [a-c].No matter in what order.
Just about checking whether there are exactly 2.

For example i used it but it doesnt work as I want.

```
/a{2}b{2}c{2}/
```

Comment: I am not expert but i think you are looking something like `/(a||b||c){2}/`

Comment: I need something to show me true if i type `aabbcc` and during that time show false for `abbbcc`

Comment: try with back-reference... `/([abc])\1/g`

Comment: @JakubSułkowski what's about `abab` ?

Comment: Is `aabbcc` the only string it should match? What would be other matches?

Answer (score 2):

As your last comment stated, I think you are looking for this:

```
^(?:([abc])\1)*$
```

Explaining:

```
^                # from start
(?:              # group without saving
    ([abc])          # group saving in $1 one of: 'a', 'b', or 'c'
    \1               # the same character saved in $1
)*               # repeat it as many as possible
$                # till the end
```

Check [live here](https://regex101.com/r/xT9cW0/2)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [back-reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) so that it has to match the same character twice.

```
/([abc])\1/
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/jU0dS7/1)

Or, for multiple back-references:

```
/(a)\1(b)\2(c)\3/
```

or

```
/(([abc])\1)*/
```

*(If you just need to literally match "aabbcc" then your regex should be* `/aabbcc/`*)*

Comment: In the second case, the backreference is pointless. It only helps if your group matches a pattern and you want to match that same pattern. For a single character, you would have better performance and the exact same result just matching the exact characters `/aabbcc/`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn That's true, in that case the regex might as well just be `aabbcc`, but if the characters are stand-ins for sub-expressions then this would be the format.

Comment: I think thats it. ! +1
Thanks

Comment: If you just need to literally match "aabbcc" then you should not use a regex.